# How to resample 6 months

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to resample 6 months in pandas? For example, I have 2 dates `'2018-02-07'` and `'2018-09-17'`. I want to resample them in 6 month period, the result should be `'2018-06-30'` and `'2018-12-31'`.

I setup the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

series = pd.Series([1,2], index=[pd.Timestamp('2018-02-07'), pd.Timestamp('2018-09-17')])
s.resample('6M').sum()
```

It gives `'2018-02-28'`, `'2018-08-31'`, `'2019-02-28'`, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this can help your purposes:

```
> series.resample('2Q', closed='left').last()

2018-06-30    1
2018-12-31    2
Freq: 2Q-DEC, dtype: int64
```

Just resampling every 2 Quarters, but closing the interval to the 'left' and getting the last value we have for each semester. More info about the aliases in pandas in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Comment: Yes, thank you! Surprisingly 2Q works but 6M doesn't.

Comment: Does not work if there are dates matching the exact end of the half year like 2018-06-30 and 2018-12-31 in the original data.