# How does pandas resample work for 6 month periods?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a simple resampling to sum values in 6-month periods. To explain my problem, I created a simple toy series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

series = pd.Series([1,2,5,6], index=[pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-06-30'),pd.Timestamp('2018-07-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-31')])
series

2018-01-01    1
2018-06-30    2
2018-07-01    5
2018-12-31    6
dtype: int64
```

Now I try to resample in 2 half-year periods, the first I wanted to go from 2018-01-01 to 2018-06-30 and sum 3, the second I wanted from 2018-07-01 to 2018-12-31 and sum 11.

Here is what I get:

```
series.resample('2Q').sum()
2018-03-31    1
2018-09-30    7
2019-03-31    6
Freq: 2Q-DEC, dtype: int64

series.resample('6M', closed='left').sum()
2018-06-30    1
2018-12-31    7
2019-06-30    6
Freq: 6M, dtype: int64
```

None is what I wanted.  I saw other questions about resampling every 6 months ([How to resample 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540019/how-to-resample-6-months)) but none showing how to prevent this specific behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way : 0 means first half 1 mean last half

```
series.groupby([series.index.year,(series.index.month-1)//6]).sum()
Out[489]: 
2018  0     3
      1    11
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by changing the frequency to Quarter start and Month start, but still do not understand the logic:

```
series.resample('2QS').sum()
2018-01-01     3
2018-07-01    11
Freq: 2QS-JAN, dtype: int64

series.resample('6MS').sum()
2018-01-01     3
2018-07-01    11
Freq: 6MS, dtype: int64
```